# Dynamic viewport meta tag ios

Tags: html, ios, ipad, viewport, meta

I have an iPad application that displays email newsletters. This HTML content is pulled and embedded inside a WebView. Most newsletter widths are 650px but some are around 900px.

By default, they display too small (iPad device width is 768px) so I want to make it zoom to fill the page (I am concerned with the width only - vertical scrolling is ok).

Using the viewport meta tag, if I hard-code 650px as the device width, it will cut off the 900px-wide newsletters. Also, setting an explicit width disables resizing the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=650, initial-scale=1">
```

However, if I set it to variable device-width, the campaign is 'squeezed' by the screen and displays off-center:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Is there a way to dynamically specify the width, so that it sets it as 650 if the campaign is <= 650, and 900 otherwise? In essence, I'm trying to set a fixed viewport dynamically based on the newsletter width. Could I use the @viewport CSS rule instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue using the strategy from my other similar question:

[Stretch/Fit HTML Template and Children to Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730252/stretch-fit-html-template-and-children-to-window)

Instead of changing the viewport meta, it turned out better in my case to dynamically scale the newsletters using JS once they were loaded.