# Stretch/Fit HTML Template and Children to Window

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, viewport, email-templates

My application generates HTML email templates. They are between 600px and 650px wide usually, but sometimes they go up to 900px. The templates are nested pretty deep (lots of `table` elements for email clients), and sadly all the widths/heights are hard-coded in px, not relative dimensions. This has been ok until now, because my users view them in a browser. But now I am building a mobile app.

I am trying to display these templates in a webview inside various mobile clients (iPhone, Android, iPad, etc). Is there a way to 'scale' or fit these templates so they stretch to fill up the entire width of the window?

I tried tweaking the meta tag;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>
```

Unfortunately I don't know the width of the template beforehand so I have to either set the meta tag too wide or too small, and then templates either have white borders or end up overlapping the window. What else can I try?

Comment: Why don't use width:100%;

Comment: I can't modify the HTML source for every template (there are thousands) and all the children elements are hard-coded in px as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CSS3's

```
transform: scale(ratio);
position: absolute;
top: 5px; left: 5px;
```

after dynamically calculating the scale ratio to take into account the 5px margin. Turns out

```
minimum-scale=0.1
```

was necessary for an older Android phone to display the re-sized view correctly.

Comment: So do you calculate the ratio in native code? Then what do you do with it? I've been struggling with a similar problem.